# Expo upgrade fail (SDK 35 -> 39)

Tags: macos, npm, expo, upgrade, yarnpkg

I have an Expo project and I am trying to upgrade from SDK 35 to 39. The command "expo upgrade" throws an error :
[the cmd failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unt0D.png)

Question :

- Is there some kind of log file I could read to know more about what went wrong ?

Infos :
[expo diagnostics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk9Lw.png)

Things I tried :

- I created a new project, just to test my installations, and Expo SDK 39 is launched with no problems.
- I tried to upgrade to SDK 36 but same issue.

Help please ^^

Comment: it looks like `npm install` failed with npm error code 243, which you can google to try to find more information. from a quick search, this seems to be a permissions issue on your machine. you could run `expo upgrade` with `sudo` but ultimately this may be masking some other issues with your node installation or other issues with your environment.